# Waiting on an indeterminate number of goroutines

Tags: go

I have code where a single goroutine will fire off an indeterminate number of child goroutines, which in turn will fire off more goroutines, etc.  My goal is to wait for all of the child goroutines to finish.

I do not know the total number of goroutines I will be firing off in advance, so I cannot use a [sync.WaitGroup](http://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup), and ideally I wouldn't have to artificially limit the total number of goroutines running via the [channel-as-semaphore](https://sites.google.com/site/gopatterns/concurrency/semaphores) pattern.

Briefly I thought of having a local channel or waitgroup in each goroutine that serves as a semaphore to wait for all its children, but that results in each goroutine hanging around consuming stack space while all of its decendants finish.

Right now my idea is to increment an [atomic counter](http://golang.org/pkg/sync/atomic/#AddInt32) when a goroutine is fired off (in the parent, to avoid spuriously hitting zero if the child starts running after the parent finishes), decrement it when a goroutine finishes, and periodically check whether it's equal to zero.

Am I basically on the right track, or is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I wrote the first implementation of `sync.WaitGroup`, and this and other edge cases were well supported. Since then the implementation has been improved by Dmitry, and given his track record I bet he's only made it safer.

In particular, you can trust that if there is currently one or more blocked `Wait` calls, and you then call `Add` with a positive delta before you call `Done`, you won't unblock any of the previously existent `Wait` calls.

So you can definitely do this, for example:

```
var wg sync.WaitGroup
wg.Add(1)
go func() {
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        wg.Done()
    }()
    wg.Done()
}()
wg.Wait()
```

I'm actually using equivalent logic in production since the code was first integrated.

As a reference, this internal comment was put in place in the first implementation, and is still there:

```
// WaitGroup creates a new semaphore each time the old semaphore
// is released. This is to avoid the following race:
//
// G1: Add(1)
// G1: go G2()
// G1: Wait() // Context switch after Unlock() and before Semacquire().
// G2: Done() // Release semaphore: sema == 1, waiters == 0. G1 doesn't run yet.
// G3: Wait() // Finds counter == 0, waiters == 0, doesn't block.
// G3: Add(1) // Makes counter == 1, waiters == 0.
// G3: go G4()
// G3: Wait() // G1 still hasn't run, G3 finds sema == 1, unblocked! Bug.
```

This is describing a different race condition to keep in mind while touching the implementation, but note that even there `G1` is doing the `Add(1) + go f()` pattern while racing with `G3`.

I understand your question, though, as there is indeed a confusing statement in the documentation that has been put there recently, but let's look at the history of the comment to see what it is actually addressing.

The comment was put there by Russ, in revision 15683:

```
(...)
+// Note that calls with positive delta must happen before the call to Wait,
+// or else Wait may wait for too small a group. Typically this means the calls
+// to Add should execute before the statement creating the goroutine or
+// other event to be waited for. See the WaitGroup example.
func (wg *WaitGroup) Add(delta int) {
```

The log comment from Russ states:

> sync: add caution about where to call (*WaitGroup).Add
>
> Fixes issue 4762.

If we read issue 4762, we find:

> It may be worth adding an explicit comment in the documentation for sync.WaitGroup that the call to Add should be done before launching the go routine containing the call to Done.

So the documentation is in fact warning against code like this:

```
var wg sync.WaitGroup
wg.Add(1)
go func() {
    go func() {
        wg.Add(1)
        wg.Done()
    }()
    wg.Done()
}()
wg.Wait()
```

This is indeed broken. The comment should just be improved to be more specific and avoid the plausible but misleading understanding you've had while reading it.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you *can* use `sync.WaitGroup` for you task, it's actually a perfect fit, designed just for that. The number of goroutines you'll create is *not* indeterminate. It's just a value known only at runtime and it is then known *exactly*. Every `go` statement creates one new goroutine. *Before* such `go` statement, regardless of how many time it'll be executed, you'll have to do

```
wg.Add(1)
```

and *insdide* every goroutine put

```
defer wg.Done()
```

as the first statement. Now you can do

```
wg.Wait
```

to wait for *all* of your goroutines to finish.

Comment: The documentation for WaitGroup states: "Note that calls with positive delta must happen before the call to Wait, or else Wait may wait for too small a group. Typically this means the calls to Add should execute before the statement creating the goroutine or other event to be waited for."  Which gives me the impression that I should not call Add in the children, if I'm waiting in a "sibling" of the parent.

Comment: @Bryce: You should call 'add' if the children itself creates more gorutine, again _before_ the relevant `go` statement. Just .Add before `go` and ensure any parent goroutine at any level does that _before_ its own return. This way the ensures the every 'Add' to the `WaitGroup` happens before its associated 'Done'. IINM ;-)

Comment: The "Adds" and "Dones" happen in the correct order, but my reading of the docs is that all your "Adds" should happen before you attempt to "Wait", which is something I can't guarantee - unless I "Wait" inside every goroutine for its children, which results in ALL of my goroutines hanging around instead of dispatching their children and returning.

Comment: @Bryce: Ah, never noticed that gotcha. Then `WaitGroup` is a broken, useless thing, at least in this case, and you have to code your own replacement. Sorry for the noise. Will delete my answer later.

Comment: Rather than delete it, just put a comment at the top saying "This doesn't actually quite work -- see comments"

It generated some good discussion and such, wouldn't help anyone to delete it all.

Comment: @MatrixFrog it *does* work, however; it's the comments that are mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

I love `WaitGroup`'s simplicity. The one thing I do not like about `WaitGroup` is having to pass a reference to it in your goroutines because you would be mixing your concurrency logic with your business logic. Moreover, in your case it could get even more complicated and error prone if you are not careful.

So I came up with this generic function to solve this problem for me:

```
// Parallelize parallelizes the function calls
func Parallelize(functions ...func()) {
    var waitGroup sync.WaitGroup
    waitGroup.Add(len(functions))

    defer waitGroup.Wait()

    for _, function := range functions {
        go func(copy func()) {
            defer waitGroup.Done()
            copy()
        }(function)
    }
}
```

So here is how I would use it to solve your problem:

```
func1 := func() {
        for char := 'a'; char < 'a' + 3; char++ {
            fmt.Printf("%c ", char)
        }
}

func2 := func() {
        for number := 1; number < 4; number++ {
            fmt.Printf("%d ", number)
        }
}

func3 := func() {
        Parallelize(func1, func2)
}

Parallelize(func3, func3)  // a a 1 1 b b 2 2 c c 3 3
```

If you would like to use it, you can find it here https://github.com/shomali11/util