# How can I block (and join) on a channel fed by an unknown number of goroutines?

Tags: recursion, go, channel, goroutine

I have a recursive function. The function will call itself with various different values depending on the data it gets, so the arity and depth of recursion is not known: each call may call itself zero or more times. The function may return any number of values.

I want to parallelise it by getting goroutines and channels involved. Each recursion of `inner` runs in its own goroutine, and sends back a value on the channel. The outer function deals with those values.

```
func outer(response []int) {

  results := make([]int)
  resultsChannel := make(chan int)

  inner := func(...) {
      resultsChannel <- «some result»;

      // Recurse in a new goroutine.
      for _, recursionArgument in «some calculated data» {
          go inner(recursionArgument)
      }
  }

  go inner(«initial values»);

  for {
      result := <- resultsChannel
      results = append(results, result)

      // HELP! How do I decide when to break?
  }

  return results
}
```

The problem comes with escaping the results channel loop. Because of the 'shape' of the recursion (unknown arity and depth) I can't say "finish after *n* events" and I can't send a sentinel value.

How do I detect when all my recursions have happened and return from `outer`? Is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: Could you be looking for a `sync.WaitGroup`? It's existence was pointed out to me [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19192377/823393) recently.

Comment: Quite possibly. That looks hopeful.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon The docs say "Note that calls with positive delta must happen before the call to Wait". That means I can't use it, surely?

Comment: @Joe: all it would mean is that `inner` should call `Add` before spawning its sub-goroutine.  If `outer` is expecting `inner` to call `Done`, then you know that the group is still active prior to that call.

Comment: Sorry @JamesHenstridge I'm not quite clear what you're saying. The first run of `inner` will run, spawn a goroutine, continue and then block on that `for` loop, or a `Wait`. The subsequent recursion will be asynchronous, so if I call `Add` inside `inner`, it will be called any number of times, including after the `Wait` has been called. Also, unless I'm missing something, my whole question is about the fact that I am unable to call `Done` because I don't know when my recursion ends..

Comment: @Joe - James is certainly more knowledgeable about `Go` than I but I would have thought you would `Add(1)` at the start of `inner`, subtract one at the end and your gathering loop merely needs to terminate when the resultsChannel is empty and the counter is at zero. Obviously there's the leading edge moment when the count is still zero to deal with.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon Yes that's what I thought, except that seems to contravene the quote above (I will be calling `Wait` before some of the `Add`s happen). The answer by 'zzzz' on this question seems to agree: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18805416/waiting-on-an-indeterminate-number-of-goroutines

Comment: @Joe - It looks like the answer in the same thread posted by Gustavo Niemeyer clears it all up - read it through to the end and he covers both techniques and the reason why one will work and the other may not. James' answer below looks like it matches the recommendations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `sync.WaitGroup` to manage the collection of goroutines you spawn: call `Add(1)` before spawning each new goroutine, and `Done` when each goroutine completes.  So something like this:

```
var wg sync.WaitGroup
inner := func(...) {
    ...
    // Recurse in a new goroutine.
    for _, recursionArgument := range «some calculated data» {
          wg.Add(1)
          go inner(recursionArgument)
    }
    ...
    wg.Done()
}
wg.Add(1)
go inner(«initial values»)
```

Now waiting on `wg` will tell you when all the goroutines have completed.

If you are reading the results from a channel, the obvious way to tell when there are no more results is by closing the channel.  You can achieve this through another goroutine to do this for us:

```
go func() {
    wg.Wait()
    close(resultsChannel)
}()
```

You should now be able to simply `range` over `resultsChannel` to read all the results.

Comment: Thank you. So the call to `wg.Wait()` happens before some of the `wg.Add(1)`s execute, correct? And is that OK? The docs say "Note that calls with positive delta must happen before the call to Wait" but I don't know if that means 'at least one call to Add' or 'all calls'.

Comment: Could you perhaps touch on why you chose not to use `defer wg.Done()`? Is that not recommended or just your preferences - it seems a good fit here as it is safe from early exits.

Comment: Since we're always calling `Add(1)` before calling `inner`, we know that the wait group's counter will always be positive in the function body (at least before the `Done` call).  Since we know the `Wait` call can not trigger here, it is safe to increment the counter further.  The race conditions occur if you let the counter momentarily hit zero early (e.g. by moving the `Add(1)` call inside `inner`).

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon: it probably is a bit cleaner to use `defer` here.  For simple cases with no early returns though, it doesn't really make a difference.  For sample code, it seemed a bit simpler to show the calls in order.

Comment: One more question. I want to poll the channel and (for example) add the results to a slice of results (let's say for the sake of example that I want to filter results before storing them). Let's also say that the size of my channel is capped. If I wait until my recursion has stopped then is my only solution to have another goroutine that monitors `resultsChannel`?

Comment: If you spawn a goroutine to close the channel when the wait group triggers like I suggest, you can start reading from the channel immediately (I'd use `for result := range resultsChannel`).  Writers to the channel will block if you aren't reading them fast enough, and the read side will block if the reverse happens.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks very much! I'll give it a try when I have time.